# I want to return rows of two tables and the lookup table that relates them efficiently. Is there a way to do this with one query?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Right now I am using three queries to get the rows that I need:

The main information from `pins`:

```
SELECT * FROM pins
WHERE lat > 45
```

The two columns from `pins_tags` that associate pins with one or more tags:

```
SELECT pins_tags.pin_id, pins_tags.tag_id FROM pins_tags
INNER JOIN pins
ON pins_tags.pin_id = pins.id
WHERE pins.lat > 45
```

And finally the information about the tags associated with the pins I just selected:

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.caption FROM tags
INNER JOIN pins_tags
ON pins_tags.tag_id = tags.id
INNER JOIN pins
ON pins_tags.pin_id = pins.id
WHERE pins.lat > 45
```

You can see I have to use the same WHERE clause in each query to get the tags associated specifically with the pins I returned in the first query. This works fine and returns exactly the three arrays that I want. But I feel like I'm not seeing a more efficient way to do this. Is there one?

Comment: should be ableto use a single query

Answer (score 0):

What I understood: Select all `tags` and the corresponding "details" from `pins_tags` and `pins`. You can choose yourself which columns should be fetched.

```
SELECT 
    tags.*
    pins_tags.*,
    pins.*
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN pins_tags ON pins_tags.tag_id = tags.id
LEFT JOIN pins ON pins.id = pins_tags.pin_id
WHERE pins.lat > 45
```

A note: The question text comparing with the title is very confusing. Please read it yourself again, but from the perspective of the user who doesn't know why you use 3 statements (arrays ?! - probably has something to do with what you've applied in PHP?) and what exactly you want to achieve :-)

Good luck.